# Cannot Save TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I am trying to create a Build definition in VS2015 TFS. When I press save button I get a Team Foundation Server Error

> Could not load assembly System.Windows, Version =2.0.5.0 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Does the issue occur on other clients? Suggest you trying it on other machines to check if that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Clean IE and TFS caches on your client. Refer to [How to clear the
  TFS cache on client machines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/) for details.  Then try it again.
- Create a build definition on another machine to check if it works.
- Check and make sure your .NET framework is patched with the latest
  patches.
- Check and make sure below `dll` exists on your TFS server:
  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Presentation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Presentation.dll`
- Try to install the [Silverlight 5 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359) on your TFS server machine.
- Edit the `web.config` file to remove the reference which is not
  required for normal operation:

  1 - Open the `web.config` file in the root of your TFS site (By default: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services` )

  2 - Find the following line and comment it out():`xxxxx`-is your
  assembly name.

  `<add assembly="xxxxx", Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`

  3 - Save and close the `web.config` file and try it again.

Comment: @user3661407 Have you resolved the issue? any update?